# Why am I getting an error while trying to load caret package?

Tags: r, r-caret

I tried:

```
library(caret)
```

then I got the error:

```
Loading required package: ggplot2
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>        namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.1 is required
>       Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.5.3

so I tried updating the ggplot2 using:

```
install.package("ggplot")
```

even after that I am getting the same error. my caret package is also updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating R package, Warning: package ‘---’ was built under R version 3.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395777/creating-r-package-warning-package-was-built-under-r-version-3-1-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try two things. One is updating your R version (and Rstudio version?). The other can be updating ggplot2 with dependencies:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```